# NServiceBus: How to get a reference to Bus if not using the generic host

Tags: nservicebus

I am trying to create a set of services that send messages to each other using NServiceBus/MSMQ.  I am doing so with NO XML configuration whatsoever, and I am also NOT planning on using the NServiceBus generic host for now (too much "black magic" with marker interfaces, profiles, containers and other crazy configuration options).

All I want to do is have my configuration be straightforward, and be completely contained in "Main()" and then be able to call Bus.Publish() in a loop or something.  I have got everything working except for I don't know how to get a reference to Bus.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
  .DefaultBuilder()
  .XmlSerializer()
  .MsmqTransport()
  .UnicastBus()
  .CreateBus()
  .Start();

bus.Send(new WhateverMessage());
```